# Почему русский текст из PDF в терминале отображается корректно, а при сохранении его в файл, отображается в виде нечитаемых символов («кракозябр»)?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

Здравствуйте.

Воспользовался библиотекой `pdfminer` (`pip install pdfminer.six`) для извлечения русского текста из файла формата PDF.

Команда `print` корректно выводит вытащенный текст в терминале. Но стоит сохранить этот вытащенный текст в файл, а затем открыть этот файл для просмотра, то вместо текста отображается абракадабра ("кракозябры").

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы текст в файле также отображался корректно?

Код:

```
import pdfminer.high_level                       # Импортируем библиотеку распознавания PDF
text_from_pdf = open("Text__from_pdf.txt", "wb") # Создаём файл, в который запишем вытащенный из PDF текст.
with open("133_1504597676.pdf", 'rb') as file:   # Открываем pdf файл для извлечения из него текста.
    pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(file, file_result_text_from_pdf) # Применяем библиотеку для разбора pdf
print("Распознавание завершено")                 # Выводим в терминал сообщение, что процесс распознавания завершен.
text_from_pdf.close()                            # Закрываем файл, в который записали результат распознавания.

with open("text_from_pdf.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file: # Открываем файл, в который помещали распознанный текст.
    file = file.read()                           # Присваиваем переменной file весь текст открытого файла.
    print(file)                                  # Выводим содержание переменной в терминал (в редакторе PyCham)
```

Текст выводится великолепно. Но в самом файле абракадабра:

[image: Абракадабра вместо текста]

Результат выполнения кода вида `print(ascii(open"text.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()))`:

[image: print (ansii(open...]

Вывод в файл в виде текста:

> * Только при покупке газеты (ред.).      2¹ 35, 6  ñåíòÿáðÿ  2017 ã. ÐÅÊËÀÌÍÀß ÑËÓÆÁÀ: ÒÅË. 42-69-28, 42-74-02, 46-77-81; ã. Åëèçîâî: 8 (41531) 7-53-30. ÐÅÊËÀÌÀ3¹ 35, 6  ñåíòÿáðÿ   2017 ã.ÏÓÍÊÒÛ ÏÐÈÅÌÀ ×ÀÑÒÍÛÕ ÎÁÚßÂËÅÍÈÉ: Òåë.: 424-666, 26-48-41. Ãàçåòà «ÑÐÎ×ÍÎ!» íóæíà âñåì!ÐÅÊËÀÌÀ4¹ 35, 6  ñåíòÿáðÿ  2017 ã. ÐÅÊËÀÌÍÀß ÑËÓÆÁÀ: ÒÅË. 42-69-28, 42-74-02, 46-77-81; ã. Åëèçîâî: 8 (41531) 7-53-30.  ×ÀÑÒÍÛÅ ÎÁÚßÂËÅÍÈßÀÂÒÎÐÅÊËÀÌÍÀß ÑËÓÆÁÀ ÃÀÇÅÒÛ «ËÓÊÎÌÎÐÜÅ ÏËÞÑ»:42-74-02,42-69-28, 46-77-81, 42-12-42Â  ÏÅÐÂÓÞ       Î×ÅÐÅÄÜПРОДАМ «ÊÈÀ-Áîíãî», ãðóçîâèê 2-êàáèí., 11 ã., 4ÂÄ îòêë., ïî-íèæ., ìîòîð ïðîñòîé, íà õîäó, îáìåí, ìîæíî íà ãðóçîâèê, 470 ò.ð. Òåë. 8-909-835-7184, 8-914-629-5415, WhatsApp. «Ì.-Òðèáüþò» 01 ã., 3,0, áåíç., àâò., 4ÂÄ, ÷åõëû, TV, 2 êàìåðû, USB, ñèãíàë., 340 ò.ð., îáìåí, ìîæíî íà ãðó-çîâèê. Òåë. 8-909-835-7184, 8-914-629-5415, WhatsApp. «Ò.-Êîðñà» 93 ã., 4ÂÄ, àâò., 1,5, áåíç., íà õîäó, 110 ò.ð. Òåë. 8-909-835-7184, 8-914-629-5415, WhatsApp.«Cadillac-Escalade» êëàññ ëþêñ, ÷åðí., 2005 ã., 1 ìëí. 100 ò.ð., òîðã, ëèáî îáìåí ñ äîïë. Òåë. 8-914-788-3309.«Lend Rover Freelander», 3-äâåð., ñèí., ëþê, àâò., ñèã-íàë., â õîð. ñîñò., 340 ò.ð., òîðã. Òåë. 8-929-456-4240.«Ssang Yong Actyon Sport» 10 ã., äèç., àâò., 4ÂÄ, ñ/ñ, ñåð., 500 ò.ð. Òåë. 8-914-620-2894, 8-958-886-4021.«Ssang Yong Istana» 2000 ã., ì/à, êàò. «Ä» + ç/÷, 150 ò.ð. Òåë. 483-748.«ÂÀÇ-21213» Íèâà – 2000 ã., áåëûé, êàðáþðàòîð, 5-òè ñòóïåí÷àòûé, â õîð. òåõ. ñîñò. Òåë. 8-918-016-6258.«ÃÀÇ-2410», êîëåíâàë, êîð-çèíó, êîëüöà è ò.ï. Òåë. 8-962-280-6288, 8-924-781-0994.«ÃÀÇ-69», ýêñêëþçèâ, áà-çà «Ò.-Ëåíä-Êðóçåð», äèç., V-3500, 5-ñòóï. êîðîáêà, òîðã ïðè îñìîòðå, öåíà äîãîâîð-íàÿ. Òåë. 8-984-163-7109.«ÇÈË-130», ñàìîñâàë, â íîðì. ñîñò., 280 ò.ð., òîðã. Òåë. 8-909-832-5355, 8-924-891-7691.«ÇÈË-554», êîëõîçíèê, ñà-ìîñâàë, 250 ò.ð. Òåë. 8-924-790-6688.«È.-Áèãõîðí» 1999 ãîä âû-ïóñêà, àâòîìàò, äèçåëü 3 ë. Ñðî÷íî. Òåë. 8-914-026-7561«È.-Ôîðâàðä», ôóðãîí, 92 ã., 5 ò. Òåë. 8-914-788-2330.«Èñòàíà» 2001 ã., 14 ìåñò, îòë. ñîñò. Òåë. 8-924-696-5919.«ÊÐÀÇ-260», ñ ç/÷. Òåë. 8-909-832-1777.«Ëåêñóñ- LX470» 03 ã., V- 4,7, àâò., 5 ñòóï., ïåðëàìóòð. öâ., ëèòüå, ñèãíàëèç., ëþê, 1250 ò.ð., èëè îáìåí. Òåë. 8-962-216-8008.«Ëåêñóñ-GÕ470» 2005 ã., 4,7, â îòë. ñîñò. Òåë. 8-961-965-6666.«Ëåêñóñ-RÕ350» 2007 ã., V-3,5, áåíç., îòë. òåõ. ñîñò., áåë., 950 ò.ð. Òåë. 8-961-969-6447.«Ëåíä-Ðîâåð-Ôðèëàíäåð» 2003 ã., âèøíÿ, áåíçèí, 177 ë.ñ., íå çàâîäèòñÿ, ðåìåíü ïîäâåñíîé, 300 ò.ð. òîðã. Òåë. 8-924-793-6189.«Ì.-MPV» 2000 Ã., 4 ÂÄ, ñ îòúåçäîì. Òåë. 8-914-625-2588.«Ì.-Ïðåìàñè» 2000 ã., â õî-ðîøåì ñîñòîÿíèè, 280 ò.ð., òîðã. Òåë. 8-914-624-5806.«Ì.-Òèòàí» òåðìîáóäêà 3 ì., äèçåëü, ìåõàíèêà, êàò «Ñ», ç/ï, 250 ò.ð. âîçìîæåí îáìåí. Òåë. 477-409.«ÌÀÇ» + ï/ïðèöåï ÎÄÀÇ, âà-ðèàíòû. Òåë. 8-909-833-7019.«Ìåðñåäåñ-Ãåëåíòâàãåí» 98 ã., â õîð. ñîñò., 1200 ò.ð. Òåë. 8-961-961-8989.«ÌÌÑ-Äåëèêà» 96 ã., V-2,8, àâò., 4ÂÄ, á/äîêóì., 280 ò.ð., òîðã. Òåë. 8-924-894-0774.«ÌÌÑ-Äåëèêà» 98 ã., ò/ñè-íèé

Comment: попробуйте открыть файл используя utf-8 кодировку (если верить вашему коду и вы не изменяли файл позже). Хотя картинка больше похожа на cp1251 -> cp1252 https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/

Comment: Здравствуйте. Благодарю вас за ответ. Поясните, пожалуйста, вы предлагаете открыть файл в Python или в операционной системе? Если в Python, то как вы можете видеть в коде, эта кодировка применяется (with open("text_from_pdf.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file). И как и было указано в тексте вопроса, то в терминале этот текст отображается великолепно. А вот когда открываешь файл в операционной системе (например, программой "Блокнот"), то выходит абракадабра (что и видно на скриншоте).

Comment: Если вы не знаете как открыть файл в выбранной кодировке в Блокноте, то задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом (notepad.exe  это приложение, python.exe это приложение, cmd.exe это приложение)

Comment: Вопрос касается именно Python, так как именно после распознавания средствами библиотеки этого языка извлекается текст из pdf и сохраняется в текстовый файл. И вот этот самый получаемый файл и показывает абракадабру. Здесь вопрос совершенно не про открытие файла с неправильной кодировкой блокнотом. А про то, почему Python записывает текст в виде абрыкадабры в этот самый файл.

Comment: какое у вас доказательство, что файл неправильный?  То что блокнот файл неправильно показывает? Какую кодировку по вашему блокнот выбирает для показа? Какая кодировка по вашему у файла? Покажите результат: `print(ascii(open(‘ваш.txt’, encoding=‘utf-8’).read()))`. Отформатируйте вопрос  (если не знаете как, спрашивайте), нажмите кнопку [edit]

Comment: Не совсем ясно, зачем править вопрос. Там всё по существу дела. Доказательства? Текст в виде абрыкадабры показывает не только блокнот, а также Word, Wordpad. При открытии они предлагают выбрать из списка нужную кодировку из списка более 30 разных этих самых кодировок, но НИ ОДНА не "излечивает" файл от абрыкадабры. Результат вашего кода добавил в вопрос.

Comment: добавьте в виде текста вывод, а не картинки.  (Если не знаете как скопировать текст или как форматирование на Stack Overflow работает, спрашивайте). Предварительно (без машинной проверки, для которой текст в виде текста, а не картинки нужен) файл нормальный. Это значит что вы просто не умеете на Windows просматривать файлы в utf-8 (происхождение файла значения не имеет — на диске только байты лежат). Начните с файла: `open(“utf8.txt”, “w”, encoding=“utf-8”).write(“\u0430\u0431\u0432”)` должны увидеть  «абв» в этом файле.

Comment: Удалось «абв» увидеть? Кстати, в коде, который файл создаёт выше,  кавычки следует поправить (телефон fancy quotes наставлял вместо обычных, не ясно почему)

Comment: Результат. Да, удалось увидеть текст "абв". Вывод в виде текста в вопрос добавил, после последнего скриншота.

Comment: Добавлю следующее. При работе с ещё одним PDF по такой же схеме, файл с распознанным текстом отображается корректно (без абрыкадабры). Значит дело в самом PDF? Может такое быть?

Comment: Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, необходимо полистать спецификацию формата PDF. Спекулируя, могу предположить, что кодировке каждого текстового фрагмента может задаваться отдельно (основываясь на том факте, что банально могут быть разные шрифты).

Comment: Так в моём случае перенести в тестовый файл распознанный текст из PDF в читаемой человеком кодировке получится или нет?

Comment: @andreymal Вы можете помочь в решении моего вопроса? Я увидел ваш ответ про кодировки и решил обратиться к вам и со своим вопросом. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете этот PDF выложить куда-нибудь?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вот ссылка на файл на гуглдиске — https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ZWvHCgsNACS29MQTRUS3dnS3c